# 3D and 2D lengths of lines in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, elevation, line, length

I have a 2D road segment and convert it into 3D using a raster in ARCGIS 9.3. So, what i see is that the length of 3D road segment is still the same as the 2D road. How can this be? As due to elevation aspect, the 3D length should be longer than the 2D counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try **[Add Surface Information](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000016000000)** and/or **[Add Z Information](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000005z000000)** which are in the 3D Analyst toolbox.